# display inline html from php search

Tags: php, mysql

Source can be found here: [results.php](http://warprunner.com/source/results.php)
and the zip: [Results zip](http://warprunner.com/source/results.zip)

```
             <?php
             
// create short variable names
$searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];

$searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);

if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {

echo '<p><strong>You have not entered search details.  Please go back and try again.</strong></p>';
        exit;

}

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    $searchtype = addslashes($searchtype);
    $searchterm = addslashes($searchterm);
}

@ $db = new mysqli("*","*","*","*");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
    exit;
}

$query = "select * from acronymns where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%' ORDER BY title ";

$result = $db->query($query);

$num_results = $result->num_rows;

echo "<p>Number of records found: ".$num_results."</p>";

for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).".  ";
    echo $row['acro'];
    echo  " - ";
    echo $row['title'];
    echo "</strong><br />";
    echo $row['desc'];
    echo "</p>";
}

//  $result->free();

$db->close();
```

Output looks like:

> 1. - Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA)
>
> The **Americans with Disabilities Act** was enacted in 1990 to establish the prohibition of discrimination on the basis of disability, which may include autism. The ADA is divided into three Titles. Title I speaks to employment law, Title II covers State and Local activities (including public transportation), and Title III relates to accommodations in public buildings and businesses.

The link is: `www.ada.com target="_blank" Americans with Disabilities Act</a>` (within the MySql db.

The actual link shows: `http://mysiteishere.com/"www.ada.com"`  which of course makes a 404 Error.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the `desc` filed contains URL's doesn't mean they will autmoatically show up as links in your HTML.  You need to output the links as an `href` value in an `<a>` element to make a clickable link.  You are probably best off not storing full HTML in your DB, but rather just the link. It looks like you combination now is producing an invalid link.  Simple look at your HTML source and fix it.

Comment: Well it does show up as a clickable URL. It's just that it puts my site name in it. It makes my <a> link a directory of the whole link.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said, it seems that you're not including the link correctly. It doesn't have anything to do with the $row['desc'] but what's inside it. When you're inserting the link from whatever form you're using, use the following.

### ex:

```
<a href="url goes here" target="_blank">Americans with Disabilities</a>
```

Comment: Yep, mine is exactly like that.

Comment: Do you have anything in your .Htaccess file? If so, edit your question and post in there.

Comment: Then update your question with what is inside $row['desc'];. I'd like to see it.

Comment: [link](http://www.warprunner.com/source/results.png)  That is a pic I took of the output. The unbolded part is the $row[desc]

Comment: Is that your website?

Comment: Nope...I link with an <a> tag to it. Or try to.

Comment: I am having a hard time to figure out what could be the issue as every a link should of course open the direct location so this is a little weird. I really can't help much without actually looking at the code at this point. But I am very sure that it's easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function while fetching 'DESC' column

```
function make_links_clickable($text){
return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);}
```

For Eg.

```
$text = 'Here is link: http://google.com And http://example.com inside. And another one at the very end: http://test.net';

echo make_links_clickable($text);
```

Comment: Well the problem isn't it's clickability...it's The actual link shows: http://mysiteishere.com/"www.ada.com" which of course makes a 404 Error. Have no idea why it's putting in the site URL with my link.

Answer (score 0):

Went ahead and changed my code and the text in the db. In the db I removed the  Text.. and put the  in between parentheses. The Php I changed to the following and now it shows the links with the urls, so it works. It's the "a href.." that I can't make work. I don't understand why though.

```
    for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
 echo "<strong>".($i+1).".  ";
 //echo $row['acro'];
 //echo  " - <br />";
 //echo "<br>";
 echo $row['title'];
 echo  " - ";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "</strong>";
 $text = $row['desc'];
 $text = preg_replace('/(^|[^"])(((f|ht){1}tp:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i','\\1<a href="\\2" target="_blank">\\2</a>', $text);
 echo $text;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

The link in the MysqlDB should be:

```
<a href="www.ada.com" target="_blank"> Americans with Disabilities Act</a>
```

Now lets assume you got this right, you should look at your charset of your DB, just making sure they match your editors charset.

That said, please post the output of HTML "Show source".

Comment: It's really a better idea to store the href of the link in the DB and build up the link in the code. What happens if you want to change an attribute of all of the links in one shot (for example)? Little bit more difficult if you have the whole link stored in the field.

Comment: A regular expression or the simplest of jquery could help you in that matter?
It says nowhere where he is going to use it, might just be inside the text. Making it mighty difficult to add afterwards.

Comment: I have used UTF-8 and Windows-1252 Here is the Source:

Comment: You can't post sources in comments, edit your question at the top instead.

Comment: Thanks...source link is at the top of the page